# How can I store and add items back to a queue

Tags: java, database, list, linked-list, queue

I don't know how to store the items from the first queue, save them and then add them back on

right now it goes through once and then the queue is empty

I know the concept just don't know the syntax

tried making a second queue and adding the players back when the queue is empty but it didn't work

````
        Queue<Baseball_PlayerItem> players = getplayers();
        int ct = 0;int outCt = 0;
        boolean game = true;
        for (Baseball_PlayerItem item : players) {
            while (game) {
                do {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    double rand2 = rand.nextDouble();
                    item = players.remove();
                    if (item.getBatAvg() > rand2) {
                        System.out.printf("\nHit Perc: %s player: %s", rand2, item.getBatAvg());
                        ct++;
                        if (ct >= 3) {
                            System.out.printf("\nAnother home run total: %s", ct);
                        }
                    } else if (item.getBatAvg() < rand2) {
                        System.out.printf("\nThats Miss");
                        outCt++;
                        if (outCt == 3) {
                            System.out.printf("\nThree outs game over :( Outs: %s",outCt);


                        }else if (players.isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.printf("\nAll done");
                            checkGameStatus();
                            game = false;
                        }
                    }

                } while (game = true);
            }
        }


    }```Okay game on inning: 1
Thats Miss
Thats Miss
Thats Miss
Three outs game over :( Outs: 3
Thats Miss
Thats Miss
Thats Miss
Thats Miss
Hit Perc: 0.12601973051909088 player: 0.323
Another home run total: 8
Thats Miss
All done
Would you like to start the game (Y/N)---->y
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
````

Answer (score 0):

First of all I noticed that the code contains many redundancies and antipatterns, for example defining a do/while inside a while is reduntant, then alternating the queue inside the for loop will eventually result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

The first player that plays removes all other players from the Queue, what's the purpose of this program?

Comment: small baseball game I'm trying to make

Comment: What is your algorithm trying to do, can you explain it's purpose